# Magento cache problem in file

Tags: magento-1.7, cache

I am facing a very big problem in magento regarding cache, I am using 1.7 version of magento and I have a file where I am checking page title but result is correct only on first hit.And after that the old cache result.
How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle();
```

you can use this code in your phtml file

Comment: thanks vivek .But it's not working

Comment: Still it is returning old value?

Comment: yes it is returning same value

Comment: Actually header and footers are set via cache in magento
Try disabling the cache then it will respond you the correct title

Comment: if i disable the cache then it will effect on my site speed.. i think you know this..

Comment: Then you have to disable cache for a particular block
here is a link how you can do that
http://www.magikcommerce.com/blog/how-to-turn-off-cache-for-an-individual-block-in-magento/
Without disabling it wont be possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30483/discussion-between-user3515241-and-vivek-khandelwal).